# Loop over every Htmlelement on a page in a WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I am trying to make a loop to find every HtmlElement from the webpage which, I am currently on in my web browser control in C#.

I've tried:

```
var elements = webbrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("textarea");

foreach (HtmlElement el in elements) {
    MessageBox.Show(el);
}
```

Comment: And what exactly have you tried? Specifically, post your code.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question with some code; however, I'm guessing that hasn't worked - correct?

Comment: @Jesse : No, it doesn't and it only was for textarea (htmlelement). I want to catch all html elements on that page.

Comment: @user2184881 I've posted an answer with what you're looking for.

Answer (score 8):

I'll post this as an answer, so that it's easy to find.

All document elements are under `webBrowser1.Document.All`.

You can iterate over them as such:

```
foreach (HtmlElement element in webBrowser1.Document.All)
{
    MessageBox.Show(element.Id);
}
```